# Microsoft Entity Framework ASP NETCore API Related Data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, api

I am building a simple API for practice which is like below:

my Student, Enrollment and Courses model is like this:

```
 public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }

namespace.Models.School
{
public enum Grade
{
    A, B, C, D, F
}
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
 }
}

 public class Course
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext is like this:

```
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

I have two methods in my controller like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetAllSudents()
    {

        var students = await _context.Students.ToListAsync();
        return (students);

    }

   [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingleStudent(int id)
    { 

    return Ok( await _context.Students
                   .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id));
     }
```

Now GetAllStudets() function works fine brings all the students in Chrome and Postman, GetSingleStudent () also brings back the single student result while it continuously loading in Chrome and with this error in the console:

```
36:1 GET http://localhost:49170/api/students/36 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

In Postman it simply says:

```
Could not get any response 
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:49170/api/students/36
```

My question is, how can I get rid of this error and improve on this Api?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that my Student table has an Enrollment collection and inside Enrollments I have Courses and inside Courses I have again Enrollments.
So it was causing self-referencing loop. To get around this I had to  create Resources classes on top of domain Models so my StudentResource look like this which is identical to my its domain Model:

```
public class StudentResource
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EnrollmentResource> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

But I had to change the EnrollmentResource class which should not contain reference to Students and Courses backwards.

```
public class EnrollmentResource
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

}
```

In my MappingProfile.cs class I mapped them like this:

```
        CreateMap<Student, StudentResource>();
        CreateMap<Enrollment, EnrollmentResource>();
```

Finally I had to changed the return of the GetSingleStudent(int id) method type like below :

```
  return Ok(_mapper.Map<Student, StudentResource>(singleStudent));
```

And the error disappread.